# Convert list of id to Object using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have objects :

```
class Group {
    public string GroupName ; 
    public List<Access> Details ; 
}

Class Access {
     public int Id;
     public string Name; 
}
```

Now I have a Dto like:

```
Class GroupDto
{
    string GroupName; 
    List<int> Details ; 
}
```

User can create/send GroupDto and converted to Group before saving.

how to define the MappingProfile for this ?

Comment: You can either create a map from Acces to int or a resolver for Details. A map feels more natural, but would it really apply elsewhere or it's more likely to be a problem?

Comment: @nightingale2k1, wasn't your question about 'Converting List of IDs to Objects'? In which case GroupDto would be source not destination. All answers demonstrate how to map from database to GroupDto and not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mapping profile just use `MapFrom` method and let AutoMapper know how to get the data like below:

```
CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
    .ForMember(
        destination => destination.Details, 
        options => options.MapFrom(
            source => source.Details.Select(detail => detail.Id).ToList()
        )
    );
```

**Side Note:** please expose a property instead of field like you did in your sample. Also make sure that properties on `GroupDto` class are `public` too.

Comment: Any idea if kinda reverse of this is possible? Here, in your example, one is mapping integers from Group Access List to GroupDto integer List. Is it possible to map GroupDto to Group and 'convert' Details List of intergers to List of Access objects (Details List in the Group class.)? One would have to access and filter the List of Access entities in Group class by comparing Access.Id to GroupDto.Details integers.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Details,
                    opt =>
                        opt.MapFrom(
                            s => s.Details.Select(x=>x.Id).ToList()))
```